# Incosistent rows updated between MySQL and go-sql-driver/mysql

Tags: mysql, go

I'm trying to update a record in the database, and based on the `rowsAffected()` count I can decided whether the record exists or not. In which case if it doesn't (`rowsAffected() == 0`) I will run a insert query.

```golang
func (u *UserService) NewAddress(l *models.Address) error {
    var err error
    db, err := database.GetConnection()
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    defer db.Close()
    sql := `UPDATE Locations SET Address = ?, StateId = ? WHERE Id = ?`
    query := `INSERT INTO Locations (UserId, StateId, Address, City, StreetName, StreetNumber, Code, Latitude, Longitude) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)`

    stmt, err := db.Prepare(sql)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    results, err := stmt.Exec("Port St Johns, South Africa", l.StateId, l.Id)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    fmt.Println(results.RowsAffected())
    if affected, err := results.RowsAffected(); err == nil {
        if affected == 0 {
            insert, err := db.Query(query, l.UserId, l.StateId, l.Address, l.City, l.StreetName, l.StreetNumber, l.Code, l.Latitude, l.Longitude)
            defer insert.Close()
            if err != nil {
                return err
            }
        }
    }
    return nil
}
```

However, the `RowsAffected()` func always returns 0 if the value of the column I'm updating e.i `Address` is the same as the one already stored in the database. It also returns 0 if it can't find the record I'm trying to update.

If I run the same query directly on MySQL console however, even if the update (address) is exactly the same, it always returns `Update Rows` >= 1 as long as the `WHERE` clause condition is met.

```sql
UPDATE Locations 
SET Address = "Port St Johns", StateId = 2 
WHERE Id = 102;
```

[image]

Can I do this update any different? I'm trying to avoid a `select` query to check if the record exists before updating/inserting.

Comment: Have you tried ROW_COUNT();?  It is not an alternative solution however you may find what is going wrong by comparing the results.

Comment: You could have a timestamp column in your table, something like `updated_at`, that you update to the current timestamp every time you issue an update query, that way the `row_count()` mysql function will always return a number greater than 0 if the update matched one or more rows. Note also that `row_count()` is defined to return only the number of rows **affected by the change** and it is therefore the MySQL console that you are using that is inconsistent with the actual mysql database output.

Comment: ... for example try running the query using the `mysql` command line tool and, when doing an update that doesn't change a single column you'll see an output like the following `Rows matched: 1  Changed: 0  Warnings: 0`, and when you subsequently call `select row_count();` you'll get back `0`. So you can see that the MySQL console UI saying `"Updated Rows 1"` in this case is misleading, incorrect, not true, false! There were no rows updated. Yes, one row was matched, but it was not updated.

Comment: As an alternative to using the `"updated_at"` column, if you want to *"avoid a `select` query to check if the record exists before updating/inserting"*, I suppose you could also use [`INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html).

Answer (score 0):

I added a `updated` timestamp as @mkopriva suggested. That way there's always an updated count even when all the data is the same, the timestamp will change/update